# Two or more pandas columns on the same seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am trying to do a scatter plot for the following data with all columns in one plot.

[image: Data for the dataframe]

Actually I imported this data from csv file and saved in a dataframe `df_inv` and then I saved it in variable tips

```
tips = df_inv
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x=df_inv.index, y = "a")
plt.show()
```

I want to add columns b, c, and d on the same plot but I am unable to find the right code. I have tried `y = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]` but it didn't worked. I want my result in the following format ideally not all circles but some x, *, and other shapes.

[image: Ideal output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could re-shape your data in a different dataframe with [**`pandas.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df_inv = df_inv.reset_index()
columns = ['index', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df_to_plot = df_inv[columns]

df_to_plot = pd.melt(frame = df_to_plot,
                     id_vars = 'index',
                     var_name = 'column_name',
                     value_name = 'value')
```

In this way, you will get something like:

```
    index column_name  value
0       0           a    315
1       1           a    175
2       2           a     65
3       3           a    370
4       4           a    419
5       0           b    173
6       1           b    206
7       2           b    271
8       3           b    463
9       4           b    419
10      0           c     58
...
```

Now you can finally plot with a single line of code:

```
sns.scatterplot(ax = ax, data = df_to_plot, x = 'index', y = 'value', style = 'column_name', hue = 'column_name')
```

### Complete code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


N = 5
df_inv = pd.DataFrame()
df_inv['a'] = np.random.randint(low = 50, high = 500, size = N)
df_inv['b'] = np.random.randint(low = 50, high = 500, size = N)
df_inv['c'] = np.random.randint(low = 50, high = 500, size = N)
df_inv['d'] = np.random.randint(low = 50, high = 500, size = N)


df_inv = df_inv.reset_index()
columns = ['index', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df_to_plot = df_inv[columns]

df_to_plot = pd.melt(frame = df_to_plot,
                     id_vars = 'index',
                     var_name = 'column_name',
                     value_name = 'value')


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.scatterplot(ax = ax, data = df_to_plot, x = 'index', y = 'value', style = 'column_name', hue = 'column_name')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, if you don't want to reshape the dataframe, will be calling sns.scatterplot several times, each time with a different column you'd like to plot in the y parameter. Then, each column will be plotted on the same axes the first call will generate. You can create lists of colors and markers to be used at each call, and also manually create a legend.
Here is the example code, using all columns in the df_inv dataframe (with some randomly generated data).

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.lines as mlines


df_inv = pd.DataFrame({'a': random.sample(range(300, 400), 5),
                       'b': random.sample(range(100, 200), 5),
                       'c': random.sample(range(40, 90), 5)},
                      index=range(1,6))

markers = ['o', 'x', 'd']
colors = ['purple', 'cyan', 'green']
legend_handles = []

for i, col_name in enumerate(df_inv.columns):
    sns.scatterplot(data=df_inv, x=df_inv.index, y=col_name,
                    marker=markers[i], color=colors[i], s=100) # s = marker size
    legend_handles.append(mlines.Line2D([], [], color=colors[i], marker=markers[i],
                                        linestyle='None', markersize=8, label=col_name))
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(handles=legend_handles, bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), title='Column')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Code result:
[image: result figure]

Answer (score 1):

- [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) accepts data in a wide form, or a long form.

  - For this OP, the simplest solution is to pass the dataframe in its current wide format.
  - > data: `pandas.DataFrame`, `numpy.ndarray`, **mapping**, or **sequence**. Input data structure. Either a **long-form** collection of vectors that can be assigned to named variables or a **wide-form** dataset that will be internally reshaped.
  - `data=df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]` or `data=df`, for selected, or all columns, respectively.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.1`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample dataframe
np.random.seed(2023)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(low=50, high=500, size=(5, 5)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

# create a figure and axes
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 4))

# plot selected columns
sns.scatterplot(data=df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']], ax=ax1, legend=False)
ax1.set(title='Selected Columns Plotted - No Purple ♦')

# plot all columns
sns.scatterplot(data=df, ax=ax2)
ax2.set(title='All Columns Plotted')

# move legend for cosmetics
sns.move_legend(ax2, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)
```

[image]

#### `df`

```
     a    b    c    d    e
0  393   75  233  467  270
1   53  422  102  407  328
2  451  289  487  481  383
3   89  266  292  181  108
4   78  259  160  249  113
```